# Reversing a date for loop with Twig

Tags: php, date, symfony, drop-down-menu, twig

I have the following dropdown in my Twig template, which produces:

2004, 2005, 2006...and so on...

However, I am trying to reverse that (2014, 2013, 2012...and so on...). I am finding the Twig [reverse](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/reverse.html) filter does not work.

Is this because I am already using the date filter?

```
<select name="cc_start_year" id="cc_start_year">
   <option value="">YYYY</option>
   {% for i in "now"|date("Y")-10.."now"|date("Y") %}
      <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
   {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: Does `{% for i in "now"|date("Y").."now"|date("Y")-10 %}` not just do it?

Comment: @Qoop Yes it does. Thank you. Do you want to submit this as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does `{% for i in "now"|date("Y").."now"|date("Y")-10 %}` not just do it?

Answer (score 0):

Did You try to use range 
range(0, 3) and date_modify
like

```
{% for i in range( "now"|date_modify('-10 years')|date('Y'), "now"|date('Y')) %}
```

or event assign `"now"|date('Y')` to variable `set year = "now"|date('Y')`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, I did play around with `range` and `date_modify`. Your example gives me exactly what I have at the moment but it does not reverse the order. `reverse` doesn't seem to play well with your example either when I try it.